# Python 3.75, importing package that is installed in edit mode

Tags: python

### Problem:

I'm setting up unit testing with `pytest` and need to import the objects I want to test. I installed the package that I am testing in edit mode. However, `from my_pkg.file import File` causes `ImportError`.

I can see the module installed with a reference to my remote repository, prepended with an `-e` semaphore when I run `pip freeze`.

I also see the egg object sitting in the package directory in /src.

### Error Message in console:

> ImportError while importing test module
> 'C:\Users\zzz\source\repos\proj\application\tests\test_file.py'.
> Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
> Traceback:
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
> from my_pkg.file import File E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_pkg'

### Package Directory:

[image]

Comment: Where does `my_pkg` exist in your directory hierarchy, and does `my_pkg/__init__.py` exist?

Comment: @chepner I added an image of the package directory to the post.

Comment: But where is `my_pkg`? It needs to be in a directory on your Python path.

Comment: @chepner my_pkg is installed in a virtual environment, not globally. I have selected the venv that it is installed on in VSCode.

Comment: I'm assuming `application/src` is not on your Python path. Aside from the interpreter-specific hard-coded default, the only directory that's implicitly added is whatever directory contains the main script, which for your tests would appear to be `tests/`. `application/src` is not, so Python won't find `my_pkg`.

Comment: @chepner I installed the package to the venv that is activated in the terminal using `pip install -e my_pkg`. When I run `pytest -v --cov .` from that terminal with cwd set to tests I would have thought that the package should be available like other packages installed, for example; `requests`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224746/discussion-between-fpsdkfsdkmsdfsdfm-and-chepner).